# Question closed as dupe but has a better answer

Tags: discussion

I was reading up on comparing nullable types to their defaults in C#, and reached [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864243/how-do-i-compare-a-generic-type-to-its-default-value). It's closed as a dupe of [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65351/null-or-default-comparsion-of-generic-argument-in-c-sharp).

The odd thing is that the first question has a "better" accepted answer -- one that covers more cases (eg. ints/strings/classes/enums) than the second question. (In the second question, the same answer is buried quite deeply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65461/210780).)

I don't know if this is "fixable." It occurs to me that we could reverse the duplication marking, and make the second question a dupe of the first instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you see this case, where a question closed as a dupe has good answers that should be included in the original, it means the questions should be merged.  Flag the duplicate question and ask for it to be merged with its duplicate.  If a mod agrees with your assessment, the answers will be added to the other question.

Comment: I had no idea this was a thing. Interesting...

Comment: Thanks, that's a great suggestion. What are the implications of merging? (How does it work?)

Comment: @ashes999 All of the answers are moved to the other question, along with their comments, votes, etc. and then the source is deleted.

Comment: Okay, awesome. I'll do that right now.

Comment: A bit of a shame for Nathan though. He will lose 46 votes if they get merged...

Comment: @user000001 I'll leave it to the mods to decide. I already added the flag and referenced this meta thread.

Comment: @user000001 at least Nathan won't lose the reputation earned since it has a score of at least +3 and been visible for more than 60 days.  See [Reputation and Historical Archives](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/). This is also sourced in the [How does reputation work faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/148672)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, the person who wrote the better answer could post it on the original, thus ensuring that the original is both the first chronologically and also the one with the best answers.

Comment: It's already posted, but buried (see my original question text).

Comment: @ashes999 I'm not seeing an answer by Gravell on the original...

Comment: that's because it's not by him. It's by Lasse V. Karlsen.

Comment: @ashes999 Ah, I see, same-ish answer, different person. Gravell's answer's actually got a bit more info on it than Karlsen's, and as the 3rd highest answer with >10 net upvotes, I wouldn't exactly call it "buried"